# Padding not working for table component in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I am trying to add padding for table head and table rows in Tailwind based React App.

Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import "./styles/tailwind-pre-build.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <table className="w-full px-2 rounded-t-md">
      <thead className="text-white bg-blue-600 text-left border border-red-600 p-2">
        <tr className="w-full p-2">
          <th className="font-medium">App Name</th>
          <th className="font-medium">Owner</th>
          <th className="font-medium">Date Created</th>
          <th className="font-medium">Scopes</th>
          <th className="font-medium">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr className="p-2">
          <td>Test App</td>
          <td>Shivam Sahil</td>
          <td>20 May 2022, 19:58 AM</td>
          <td className="break-words">all.create all.update all.read</td>
          <td>Edit</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

For some reason the padding doesn't seem to happen at all. I tried to inspect and check but even when adding padding in styles it won't show up, can someone help me understand what wrong am I doing here?

Here's the live sandbox:https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-xwvdue?file=/src/App.js:0-884

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the padding inside the cells, so instead of `<tr>` you need set padding for all `<th>`, `<td>` tags.

```html
<table className="w-full rounded-t-md">
  <thead className="text-white bg-blue-600 text-left border border-red-600">
    <tr className="w-full">
      <th className="font-medium p-2">App Name</th>
      <th className="font-medium p-2">Owner</th>
      <th className="font-medium p-2">Date Created</th>
      <th className="font-medium p-2">Scopes</th>
      <th className="font-medium p-2">Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td className="p-2">Test App</td>
      <td className="p-2">Shivam Sahil</td>
      <td className="p-2">20 May 2022, 19:58 AM</td>
      <td className="break-words p-2">all.create all.update all.read</td>
      <td className="p-2">Edit</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

##### OR

Instead of adding  the `p-2` class everywhere using the Tailwind Utilities, you will get the same result.

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  td,
  th {
    @apply p-2;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Comment: thank you very much what you suggested worked however I wanted to know why it didn't work when we apply it at top level

Comment: This is weird for me too, but it's the [www.w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#value-def-padding-width) specification and just need to remember this exception.

Comment: I've found that setting the padding on the first ```<td>``` or ```<th>``` tag sets it for all cells if you hate being repetetive

Answer (score 0):

We need to apply padding for every `th` or `td` tag . So I suggest applying it in global css like this :

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  tr th {
    @apply p-3;
  }
  tr td {
    @apply p-3;
  }
}
```